# copy windows from unbootable ssd to new ssd

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, clone

I have an Smasung evo 850 SSD which has become unbootable.

I have installed a new EVO870 and installed windows 10.

The old SSD is visible in windows file explorer and appears to be fine when checking disk manager.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYix.png)

Is there any way to copy the windows installation from the 850 -> 870.
Does Creating an image of the 850 include potentially imaging the issue which is casuing the 850 fail to boot ( INACESSABLE BOOT DEVICE)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, the problem will be exactly the same and you just destroyed your working OS. If the old drive is accessible then you can recover your personal files - the only thing that MAKES SENSE -, the software you had installed there can and should be reinstalled.

Comment: Thanks -- that was what I figured - was hoping not to have to reinstall eveything as most of the software was installed on another drive - but bviously th windows registry isnt awarte of this